# How to skip "Names" when reading text from a file?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, input

I am writing a program in which iam supposed to read from a file, skip all name of people and process other info.

What logic should i use for skipping reading names.

I read words from a file,then using their freq of occurence make a word cloud. 
For trivial things like articles i made a list and made sure that if read word are in this article list,they are not counted.(I did this using dictionary)

However iam not able to understand how can i skip reading Names.

```
WordList=[]

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if len(word)>3:
                if word not in IgList:
                    WordList.append(word.lower())


# Get a set of unique words from the list

word_set =[]


for word in WordList[::-1]:
    if word not in word_set:
        word_set.append(word)


# create your frequency dictionary
freq = {}
# iterate through them, once per unique word.
for word in word_set:
    freq[word] = WordList.count(word) / float(len(WordList))

size=[]##Size of each word is stored here
for i in word_set:
    size.append(100*freq[i])

for i in range(0,len(word_set)):
    print size[i],word_set[i]
```

Comment: do you mind sharing your work so far ?

Comment: What kind of information are you dealing with?

Comment: i am creating a  Word Cloud using python by using pygame libraries.

Comment: I assume you mean you are counting frequencies of words in a text but are to ignore names - if so I would suggest checking if each word is in a dictionary and ignoring ones that aren't.

Comment: yes i already did.Check above ,however how to skip "Names",Proper Nouns.

Comment: Why downvotes.? i thought the ques is pretty valid and i didn't find any duplicate thread on forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming sentences USUALLY start with articles and "Names" start with a **Capital letter**

```
IgList=list of articles 


with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
                if word not in IgList:
                    if word[0] not in word.upper():##Cheking if first letter is Capital
                        WordList.append(word.lower())
```

If a word starts with a Capital Letter,it is skiped.
Extra code can be written to skip the first read word.

Answer (score -2):

```
with open("filename") as f:
    rd=f.readlines()
    print (rd[:x])
```

`x` is the index number after `names`, assumed you know where is the names in your file. Basically it will skip the names. For example if your file like this;

```
John 25 USA
Mary 26 Bangladesh
Usain 63 Republic of the Congo
```

You have to write;

```
print (rd[1:])
```

or if it's like this;

```
63 Republic of the Congo Usain
26 Bangladesh Mary
25 USA John
```

You have to type;

```
print (rd[:1])
```

Comment: i will not know the position of nouns,the files will be random.

Comment: what you mean 'random' ?

Comment: any text file can be given as input, names can be anywhere in those files.

Comment: You should make an artificial intelligence